# svg is completely invisible in custom navigation bar

Tags: html, css, svg

I'm trying to replicate Razer's website and I downloaded their razer icon as an svg.

```js
import "./NavigationBar.css";
import { ReactComponent as Logo } from "./razer-ths-logo.svg";

const NavigationBar = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <ul className="nav">
                <li>
                    <Logo />
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="a">Store</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="a">PC</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="a">Console</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="a">Mobile</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="a">Lifestyle</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="a">Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="a">Community</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="a">Support</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <Logo />
        </div>
    );
}

export default NavigationBar;
```

```css
.nav {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}
```

This is what my current website looks like. The SVG should be within the circled blue area. How do I display it? Is the background color covering up the SVG? I've also displayed the SVG below my navigation bar and it works, so the issue is not with the SVG.
[image]

Comment: is the svg showing in the html inspector? maybe you need to color it with css property `.nav svg {fill: #fff}`

Comment: @Sysix the svg element is showing in the html inspector. I have tried your suggestion but there was no change.

Comment: can you give us the svg content?

Comment: @Sysix https://assets2.razerzone.com/images/phoenix/razer-ths-logo.svg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue by adding the following

import logo from './razer-ths-logo.svg';

to the top.
I then set src={logo}
I'm not sure why this is the fix, but at least it works. I just copied this from the files right after you do npm-create.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be because you did not give dimensions for the SVG image. When `li` has `display: inline-block`, the SVG image is rendered at 0x0 (according to Developer Tools.) Otherwise, the image is rendered at its full intrinsic size.

For this example, I gave the image `width: 1em`

```
.nav img {
  width: 1em;
}
```

```css
.nav {
    background-color: black;
    width: 100%;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 0px;
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 40px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.nav a {
    font-size: 16px;
    color: gray;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.nav a:hover {
    color: white;
}

.nav img {
  width: 1em;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
      <img src="https://assets2.razerzone.com/images/phoenix/razer-ths-logo.svg">
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Store</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">PC</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Console</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Mobile</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Lifestyle</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Services</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Community</a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="#">Support</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I added your suggestion and set not only the width but also the height of the img to 1em. The issue now is that the img is rendered at 16x16, but it is completely invisible like before.

Comment: @codingcultivator445 The image is visible in my snippet, so you'll have to show a working demo of it still not being visible when it is rendered with the given dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

*To solve your issue there could be a couple of things:*

A) The **SVG Images is rendered or not**: You could use 'inspect element' to see if it is either rendered or not. If it is not rendered, kindly use correct reference and URL link to import so that it is imported.

B) The SVG is rendered - then, the **change the inside fill-color and color-of-border in svg file**, you could open any SVG file -- in even notepad.

C) If still there is issue with collision with background, **use CSS properties** - to provide a white border to SVG Image, you'll be able to fix issue, once you confirm the image has been rendered.